# ¸Exported Game Not working in Godot 3.3.3

Tags: godot

I almost finished my game, but there is another problem. everytime i click to play in in the exported game, these error messages show up:

[image]

I'd appreciate help!

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the error messages as text, not as pictures.

Comment: Please also use a more meaningful title. It looks like you added an unusual character to circumvent a validation.

Comment: Does all the scenes load correctly when running from the editor? Did you exclude the scenes or their resources in the export preset?

Comment: Do you move the exe to a different folder after you export it? Verify if it works right after exporting.